# Plotting % differences

Tags: python, plot, jupyter

I am working on plotting the percent differences between two data sets with year as a constant on the x axis and percent difference on the y axis. I'm new to Jupyterlab and have made a few plots with this data, but only heatmaps and step plots. When I calculate my % differences (I'll include the code input after), I only get negative numbers which doesn't make sense because the difference between data set y and data set x is positive. Here is a shortened example of what the data set looks like:

```
1980-01-01       0        0     8
1981-01-01       0        0    10
1982-01-01       0        0     2
1983-01-01       0        0     4
```

^ data set 1, titled H5

```
1980-01-01       0        0     2
1981-01-01       0        0     3
1982-01-01       0        0     0
1983-01-01       0        0     2
```

^data set 2, titled CP

I am trying to calculate % differences between the last column; for example, between 8 and 2, 10 and 3, etc.

Here is the code I have been using to get the % differences:

```
diffs = []
for x, y in zip(MELT_data_h5['MELT'], MELT_data_CP['MELT']):
    sum = ((y - x) / x) * 100
    diffs.append(sum)
```

When I print this, I get these numbers:

````
[-75.0, -70.0, -100.0, -50.0, -90.9090909090909, -60.0, -100.0, -79.16666666666666, -57.692307692307686, -68.0, -64.1025641025641, -40.74074074074074, -72.22222222222221,
``` etc. 

I assumed these weren't right because of their consistent negative values, but tried to plot anyways. 

Here's the code I used to try to plot:

    > plt.xlim(datetime.datetime(1980,1,1), datetime.datetime(2023,1,1))
    > plt.ylim(-100,0) plt.xlabel('Year',fontsize='15') plt.ylabel('%
    > difference',fontsize='15') plt.show()

Then I just get a blank plot with no data values. 
To distill this lengthy post, what I'm looking for is an accurate route to get percent differences and a real plot. 

Thank you so much.
````

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

> ***Note:*** Below I have added the thoughts and code to solve your problem. I have noticed a few issues with your function for percent difference and other things in your question however to save time I have omitted trying to correct it directly and instead just opted for trying to address the core problem at hand.

You can calculate the percentage difference using the following formulas:

[image: Percentage Difference Formula]

[image: Absolute Difference Formula]

- This will give a negative result when Value 2 is less than Value 1, which might be the case with your datasets (i.e if the values in the CP dataset are less than those in H5 and you decide to calculate the difference that way around).

  - This shouldn't be a problem as far as I can tell but if it is you can calculate the absolute percentage difference instead (provided below too).
- The negative sign indicates that Value 2 is smaller than Value 1. You can then plot these percentage differences over time.

Here's how you can do it in Python using pandas and matplotlib:

#### Standard percentage difference

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

# Create your dataframes
data_h5 = {
    "Date": pd.to_datetime(["1980-01-01", "1981-01-01", "1982-01-01", "1983-01-01"]),
    "MELT": [8, 10, 2, 4]
}
data_cp = {
    "Date": pd.to_datetime(["1980-01-01", "1981-01-01", "1982-01-01", "1983-01-01"]),
    "MELT": [2, 3, 0, 2]
}

df_h5 = pd.DataFrame(data_h5).set_index("Date")
df_cp = pd.DataFrame(data_cp).set_index("Date")

# Calculate the percent differences
diffs = []
for x, y in zip(df_h5['MELT'], df_cp['MELT']):
    if x != 0:  # Avoid division by zero
        diff = ((y - x) / x) * 100
        diffs.append(diff)
    else:
        diffs.append(0)  # You can decide what to do when x is zero

# Plot the percent differences over time
years = df_h5.index

plt.plot(years, diffs, marker='o')
plt.xlim(datetime.datetime(1980,1,1), datetime.datetime(1983,1,1))
plt.ylim(-110, 110)  # Adjusted to include possible negative differences
plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Percent difference', fontsize=15)
plt.title('Yearly Percent Difference between Dataset 1 and Dataset 2', fontsize=15)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

This code will result in a line plot with the yearly percent difference between the two datasets. The plot will include negative values to indicate when the second dataset's values are smaller than the first one's. The code also handles cases where the denominator (Value 1) is zero to avoid a division-by-zero error.

Here is the plot generated:

[image: Standard Percentage Difference Plot]

#### Absolute percentage difference

Exact same code just with the percentage calculation containing the `abs` value instead

```py
# Now let's calculate the percent differences using absolute values to avoid negative results

diffs = []
for x, y in zip(df_h5['MELT'], df_cp['MELT']):
    if x != 0:  # Avoid division by zero
        diff = abs((y - x) / x) * 100
        diffs.append(diff)
    else:
        diffs.append(0)  # You can decide what to do when x is zero
```

Plot generated:

[image: Absolute Percentage Difference Plot]